# json newtonsoft serialization records combined

Tags: .net, json, json.net

We have a web service that returns json using NewtonSoft JSON marshalling.  I'm seeing something odd in a particular call that returns multiple records in one json structure.  The issue is that the marshalling always "breaks" on one field in the output (screenshot is an online json formatter/validator):
[Invalid output json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onlc7.png)

It appears to mash two records together with 3 periods in between two attributes!  Here is what the problem area looks like as text (note the third row down):

```
 "Play":"Paper",
 "PlayerGuid":"5c3386f6-1a2d-40ab-bec1-88bc1de5a9f8",
 "PreviousChangeGameN...ltSinceLastChange":"0",
 "CalcGameNumberGapSinceLastChange":"0",
 "CalcLastStrategyChangeGameNumber":"673",
```

I end up with multiple attributes with the same name, which the online validator flags.  Funny thing is I see no errors in logs, nor from the  html/javascript that consumes the data.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: Have you examined the raw JSON returned by the web service?  Is it missing chunks in the middle?

Comment: Also, might you please [edit] your question to include your JSON **as text**, rather than as a screen shot?  On stackoverflow we ask that questions include textual data such as code, error messages, exception details and data (JSON, XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: Json.Net will not do what you are describing.  Are your sure it's not just the viewer you are using that is abbreviating the JSON?